# Rails : carrusel dies after come back to home

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with the carrousel of my page. If i go to 127.0.0.1:3000/ it works perfectly. But if go to products page, and then come back to home from the nav-bar, the home page loads without the carrousel. There is no errors in the log file and no error in the javascipt console. So I'm kind of blind with this...

this is the carrousel:

```
    <!-- Banner -->
      <section class="tm-banner" name="home">
      <!-- Flexslider -->
      <div class="flexslider flexslider-banner">
        <ul class="slides">
          <li>
            <div class="tm-banner-inner">
                <h1 class="tm-banner-title"><span class="tm-yellow-text"> SAN MARTIN </span> <br>HERRAMIENTAS </h1>
            </div>
          <img src="/assets/carrusel/carrusel-01.jpg" />
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="tm-banner-inner">
                <h1 class="tm-banner-title">AlQUILER <span class="tm-yellow-text">Y VENTA </span></h1>
                <p class="tm-banner-subtitle">El mejor servicio</p>
                <a href="#more" class="tm-banner-link">Ver Más</a>  
            </div>
            <img src="/assets/carrusel/carrusel-02.jpg" />
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="tm-banner-inner">
              <h1 class="tm-banner-title">REPUESTOS <span class="tm-yellow-text">Y ACCESORIOS</span></h1>
              <p class="tm-banner-subtitle">De Herramientas eléctricas</p>
              <a href="#more" class="tm-banner-link">Ver Más</a>    
            </div>
              <img src="/assets/carrusel/carrusel-03.jpg" />
          </li>
      </ul>
    </div>      
</section>
```

And it uses this script at the end of the page:

```
<script>
    $(function() {

        // https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/
        $('a[href*=\\#]:not([href=\\#])').click(function() {
            if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
              var target = $(this.hash);
              target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
              if (target.length) {
                $('html,body').animate({
                  scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, 1000);
                return false;
              }
            }
        });         
    });
    $(window).load(function(){
        // Flexsliders
        $('.flexslider.flexslider-banner').flexslider({
            controlNav: false
        });
        $('.flexslider').flexslider({
            animation: "slide",
            directionNav: false,
            slideshow: false
        });
    });
</script>
```

And also there is call to this .css

```
/*
 * jQuery FlexSlider v2.5.0
 * http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/
 *
 * Copyright 2012 WooThemes
 * Free to use under the GPLv2 and later license.
 * http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 *
 * Contributing author: Tyler Smith (@mbmufffin)
 * 
 */
/* ====================================================================================================================
 * FONT-FACE
 * ====================================================================================================================*/
@font-face {
  font-family: 'flexslider-icon';
  src: url('fonts/flexslider-icon.eot');
  src: url('fonts/flexslider-icon.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('fonts/flexslider-icon.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/flexslider-icon.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/flexslider-icon.svg#flexslider-icon') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
/* ====================================================================================================================
 * RESETS
 * ====================================================================================================================*/
.flex-container a:hover,
.flex-slider a:hover,
.flex-container a:focus,
.flex-slider a:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.slides,
.slides > li,
.flex-control-nav,
.flex-direction-nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.flex-pauseplay span {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
/* ====================================================================================================================
 * BASE STYLES
 * ====================================================================================================================*/
.flexslider {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.flexslider .slides > li {
  display: none;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.flexslider .slides img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.flexslider .slides:after {
  content: "\0020";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
html[xmlns] .flexslider .slides {
  display: block;
}
* html .flexslider .slides {
  height: 1%;
}
.no-js .flexslider .slides > li:first-child {
  display: block;
}
/* ====================================================================================================================
 * DEFAULT THEME
 * ====================================================================================================================*/
.flexslider {
  margin: 0 0 60px;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 4px solid #ffffff;
  position: relative;
  zoom: 1;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: '' 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: '' 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -o-box-shadow: '' 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: '' 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.flexslider .slides {
  zoom: 1;
}
.flexslider .slides img {
  height: auto;
}
.flex-viewport {
  max-height: 2000px;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.loading .flex-viewport {
  max-height: 300px;
}
.carousel li {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.flex-direction-nav {
  *height: 0;
}
.flex-direction-nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: -20px 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 10;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.flex-direction-nav a:before {
  font-family: "flexslider-icon";
  font-size: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  content: '\f001';
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
.flex-direction-nav a.flex-next:before {
  content: '\f002';
}
.flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {
  left: -50px;
}
.flex-direction-nav .flex-next {
  right: -50px;
  text-align: right;
}
.flexslider:hover .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {
  opacity: 0.7;
  left: 10px;
}
.flexslider:hover .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.flexslider:hover .flex-direction-nav .flex-next {
  opacity: 0.7;
  right: 10px;
}
.flexslider:hover .flex-direction-nav .flex-next:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.flex-direction-nav .flex-disabled {
  opacity: 0!important;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  cursor: default;
}
.flex-pauseplay a {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 10px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  z-index: 10;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #000;
}
.flex-pauseplay a:before {
  font-family: "flexslider-icon";
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  content: '\f004';
}
.flex-pauseplay a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.flex-pauseplay a.flex-play:before {
  content: '\f003';
}
.flex-control-nav {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -40px;
  text-align: center;
}
.flex-control-nav li {
  margin: 0 6px;
  display: inline-block;
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
}
.flex-control-paging li a {
  width: 11px;
  height: 11px;
  display: block;
  background: #666;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  cursor: pointer;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -o-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.flex-control-paging li a:hover {
  background: #333;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
.flex-control-paging li a.flex-active {
  background: #000;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  cursor: default;
}
.flex-control-thumbs {
  margin: 5px 0 0;
  position: static;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.flex-control-thumbs li {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
}
.flex-control-thumbs img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  opacity: .7;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.flex-control-thumbs img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.flex-control-thumbs .flex-active {
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: default;
}
/* ====================================================================================================================
 * RESPONSIVE
 * ====================================================================================================================*/
@media screen and (max-width: 860px) {
  .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 10px;
  }
  .flex-direction-nav .flex-next {
    opacity: 1;
    right: 10px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem of turbolinks. You need to add an event listener to one of the turbo links events

```
$(document).on ('turbolinks:load', function (){
   $('.flexslider.flexslider-banner').flexslider({
        controlNav: false
    });
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        directionNav: false,
        slideshow: false
    });
})
```